# How to prevent from 'The thread has exited with code 0 (0x0)'?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I am designing a real time spectrum analyzer. Currently, process is generating white noise, sending it to output buffer, receiving from input buffers with feedback, taking FFT and pushing magnitude, frequency values to the user control named spectrumAnalyzer1. While debugging the code, the audio i/o process eventually stops (while the program still runnning) and I get "The thread "x" has exited with code 0 (0x0)" message in the output window.

The exiting thread is always the thread that executes this code block:

```
void asio_DataAvailable(object sender, AsioAudioAvailableEventArgs e)
        {
            AsioSampleType sampleType = e.AsioSampleType;
            int numberOfSamples = e.SamplesPerBuffer;

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("wave");

            for (int i = 0; i < e.InputBuffers.Length; i++)
            {
                Marshal.Copy(e.InputBuffers[i], inputBufferByte, 0, numberOfSamples * 4);
                this.ConvertBytesToFloat(inputBufferByte, inputBufferFloat, numberOfSamples);
                SignalGenerator.GenerateWhiteNoise(outputBufferFloat, numberOfSamples);
                this.ConvertFloatToBytes(outputBufferFloat, outputBufferByte, numberOfSamples);
                Marshal.Copy(outputBufferByte, 0, e.OutputBuffers[i], numberOfSamples * 4);
            }

            fftProcessor.FFT(inputBufferFloat, 0, fftOutput);

            for (int i = 0; i < fftSize / 2 + 1; i++)
            {
                outputPoints[i].X = i;
                outputPoints[i].Y = Convert.ToSingle(fftOutput[i].LogMagnitude());
                shiftedIndexes[i] = (float)Math.Log(i, 2);
            }
            spectrumAnalyzer1.update(fftSize, samplingRate, outputPoints, shiftedIndexes);
            e.WrittenToOutputBuffers = true;
            spectrumAnalyzer1.Invalidate();
        }
```

And The Caller Function:

```
private void asioStartPlaying()
        {
            var asioOut = new AsioOut(1);
            BufferedWaveProvider wavprov = new BufferedWaveProvider(new WaveFormat(samplingRate, 16, 1));
            asioOut.AudioAvailable += new EventHandler<AsioAudioAvailableEventArgs>(asio_DataAvailable);
            asioOut.InitRecordAndPlayback(wavprov, 1, 0);
            asioOut.Play();
        }
```

All the audio input/output process works correctly until somehow, this block/thread's termination.

Any help will be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Might be caused by an untrapped exception. Can you reproduce the error while running under the debugger? Or can you call the method from a try/catch so you can add an exception handler to report any exceptions?

Comment: @MatthewWatson actually It's called from another function that i forgot to add. I edited the question and added the caller function. Apparently, method is called when the 'AudioAvailable' event is fired. Do you think it has something to do with this?

Comment: The odds that you can call spectrumAnalyzer1.update() directly are not good, this normally requires using Invoke() so the update() call runs on the UI thread.  For a quick check, comment out the call and add Debug.WriteLine() to see if it now keeps going.

Comment: As Matthew Watson has said, what's almost certainly happening is that the method is throwing an exception, but you aren't catching it. Add exception handling logic and your problem will likely become clear.

Comment: After I inserted try/catch block to the method, 'System.NullReferenceException' has occured and output message says "Symbols for the module 'NAudio.dll' were not loaded." even though NAudio looks loaded in the solution explorer. Is this all about the library(NAudio)? Is there a way to fix it?